# Netflow/IPfix Analyzer for network threats and anomalies

Tags: firewall, network-monitoring, security, netflow

I'm evaluating various options for Netflow/IPfix based analyzers which focus on identifying security threats and anomalies. It would be highly appreciated if someone can provide a list of tools with the following points in mind.

- windows or *nix based .. doesn't matter.
- proprietary tool or open source ... doesn't matter but open source would be good.
- price .. doesn't matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Cisco maintains a nice list of Netflow Software:
[freeware](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/iosswrel/ps6537/ps6555/ps6601/networking_solutions_products_genericcontent0900aecd805ff72b.html), [commercial](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/iosswrel/ps6537/ps6555/ps6601/networking_solutions_products_genericcontent0900aecd805ff728.html), [Cisco solutions](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/iosswrel/ps6537/ps6555/ps6601/networking_solutions_products_genericcontent0900aecd805ff720.html)

Comment: Another one not included in Cisco's freeware list is [NfDump](http://nfdump.sf.net) (collector) and [NfSen](http://nfsen.sf.net/) (Web GUI for NfDump). Their license is BSD-style.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:
Cisco just acquired Cognitive Security. They provide only threat detection.  No flow reporting.  Price = ??

Scrutinizer from Plixer : They perform threat detection and are leaders in reporting especially on firewall exports.  They automate host reputation lookups. Price = moderate

Arbor Networks : They are leaders in threat detection and have some flow reporting. It is massively scalable. Price = expensive.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider when looking at analyzers:

- Where is your NetFlow data coming from? If you've already got routers and switches that export NetFlow, you're probably in good shape, but if not, there are a number of free flow exporters available as software.
- Are you looking to buy a ready-to-deploy box, or a software solution to run on hardware that you provide yourself?
- How long of a data history do you need? Are you looking for a full-fidelity store, or are you OK with aggregation?

The company I work for produces a NetFlow analyzer called FlowTraq. For obvious reasons, I'm a fan :)

Other commercial offerings include SolarWinds, Arbor Networks, and Lancope. I believe Cisco has their own offerings as well. nTop and SiLK are two good open source tools; even if you wind up going with a commercial tool, I recommend trying them out just to get familiar with the terminology, and figure out what features you need in a NetFlow tool.